# Html web page paragraph : set text size in two different computers

Tags: html, text

I'm designing a web page. I set the title font size :"24". There are no problems in my computer, but when I use my school computer, the font is set to a maximum size of "12" and can't be edited by Notepad ++. In my pc there are never problems of this kind. I think this problem is caused by browser settings, but I have no idea how to modify them.

the second PC is an HP G5 255 Notebook. RAM 4GB. Software version : Windows 10

Comment: We have no idea how to change the browser settings of the unspecified browser running on the unspecified operating system that the computer has.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I edit the question @Quentin

Comment: unitless font sizes are illegal.  Any value other than 0 must include a unit (e.g. relative values like `em` or `%` or absolute values like `px`).  If you are not including a unit with `24`, then it's probably using the default value for that browser/OS.  Are you in fact only using `24` or is it `24px` or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to know what restrictions are being imposed by your school computer's browser so we may not be able to help you. You might be better off asking someone at the school. The only thing I can suggest is using a text-size percent instead of a specific "pixel" sized font (24px) Font sized with percent or "em" units are much more flexible.

So, instead of: `font-size: 24px`

Try: `font-size: 200%`

Check out this link: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Do you mean to have `font-size: 24px` and `font-size: 200%`?

Comment: No, INSTEAD OF using text-size: 24px, USE: text-size: 200%  You didn't provide the code you were using so I assumed you were trying to set the font-size by using "24px". Use "200%" instead and that may work.

Comment: There must be some confusion here.  I'm not OP.  I'm just a fellow developer.  I was just pointing out that I think you're trying to specify the CSS property of `font-size` but accidentally wrote it as `text-size`.

Comment: Oh, yes I did. I'll fix that. I haven't had my coffee yet this morning. :)